# Cor Padrão de Background

Tags: android

Qual a cor padrão do Background de uma nova activity no Android Studio, em Hexadecimal? Sendo que a mesma não é completamente branca (#FFFFFF)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perguntaram isso há dois anos no SO em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507370/what-is-the-default-layout-background

E a resposta marcada como correta dizia que o tema *light* tem por fundo `#EEEEEE`, que é quase branco, mas não chega a ser totalmente branco. Depois a resposta foi editara para incluir que em versões mais recentes é `#FAFAFA`, que é ainda mais branco (e na minha opinião mais fácil de pronunciar).

Comment: Bacana... Meu android é api 22 e o que funcionou pra mim, foi a cor #EEEEEE... Obrigado! nao posso dar up vote (não sei pq) mas, +1 pra ti!

Comment: @ManfrinyPereira quando você tiver quinze pontos, vai poder dar voto positivo. Se você aceitar a minha resposta como correta você ganha mais dois pontos ;)

Comment: A resposta foi excelente! Para mim a resposta já está como 'aceita', não vi nenhum botão, ou link do tipo 'aceitar esta resposta como correta'.. se puder me ajudar, onde posso aceitar essa resposta como correta?

Comment: @ManfrinyPereira É um "V" cinza abaixo do botão de votar negativo.